# запуск программы exe python 3 с вводом данных

Tags: python, subprocess

Есть скомпилированная программа name.exe. Ей на вход(методом "input") подается какое-то число, и она выводит какой-то результат. Как на python-e запустить эту программу, и подать ей на вход, например, число 5, и получить результат вывода?

Comment: Создать графический интерфейс пользователя с полем ввода

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, следует использовать модуль subprocess
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: А какие именно надо подать значения, чтобы "заполнить" input?